# MYSQLI_NUM_ROWS ALWAYS RETURNING 0

Tags: php, syntax, mysqli

i'm trying to get rid of a bug ASAP. I'm using mysql_num_rows but it ALWAYS returns 0. And i dont know if it's because i have the wrong syntax or what... can you guys help me? here's the code;

```
<?php
include_once("checklogin.php");
$u = "";
if(isset($_GET["u"])){
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} else {
    header("location: http://www.myswesite.com/login.php");
    exit();    
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
if($numrows < 1){
    echo "User does not exist or is not yet activated, press back";
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Try testing the Query directly in MySQL, what is th result?

Comment: Try `if($numrows ==0)` instead of `if($numrows < 1)`

Comment: It's probably your preg_replace call.

Comment: `var_dump($_GET);` see what results you get from that.

Comment: Try also `if(mysqli_num_rows($user_query) == 0)` and if you do, don't use it with `$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);`

Comment: tried all of these, none of em seemed to work :/

Comment: Did you try doing `var_dump($_GET);` ?

Comment: If you use `var_dump($_GET);` and returns nothing, then the problem is with your opening statements. I can't help you any further than that. Good luck with that.

Comment: yes i tried using this, and I got it to work :) thanks for your input Fred!

Comment: You're welcome. What did you end up doing to make it work?

Comment: for some reason, in the ($numrows ==0) ==" did not work. very strange... only the = worked. didnt expect that at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there is a syntax error in your query when you are passing username try this i think it works for you.

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
   SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE Username='".$username."'
```

Comment: hmmm good point, I got it to work and I fixed this syntax error as well. thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You have to use **store_result** to buffer the result set before you can get the num rows.

```
$user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
mysqli_store_result($connection);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php:

> For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved.