# php: mysqli_num_rows is returning 0

Tags: php, mysqli

I know this might be a duplicate on:
[php - MYSQLI_NUM_ROWS ALWAYS RETURNING 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558502/mysqli-num-rows-always-returning-0)
[php - mysqli_num_rows() is always returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558424/mysqli-num-rows-is-always-returning-0)

---

The thing is none of them is giving me an answer for my problem.

---

This is an example code of my code with the same syntaxes as I used.


index.html

```
<html>
    <head><title>GAS - Give Away System - Create User</title></head>
    <body>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname" /><br><br>
        <p id="errors"></p>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
                setInterval(function(){
                    $("#errors").load("php/errorchecking.php?c=username&v="+document.getElementById('uname').value);
                }, 500);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

php/errorchecking.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'gas');
    if(isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['v'])){
        echo 'Current value: ', $_GET['v'], '<br>This value is set for: ', $_GET['c'], '<br><br>';

        if($_GET['c']==="username"){
            if($_GET['v']===null){
                echo "Sorry, this username is empty! Please write a username!";
            }else{
                // I know this is open for SQL Injection, it's not in my worries.
                $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='{$_GET['v']}'";
                $sql = $con->query($query);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                    echo "Sorry, this username is already in use! Please choose something else";
                }else{
                    echo "Username avaible!"; //This is line 17
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'This is an invalid form!';
    }
?>
```

Now lets say I have a username in my table called User15, and someone's input is the exact same it will display the message `"Username available!"` from *php/errorchecking.php* **Line**:**17**

Why does it do that? Since it already is a user there called `User15`, so what it should display is `"Sorry, this username is already in use! Please choose something else"`

Thanks for taking time helping me! Cecilie.

Comment: $query = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE username='".$_GET['v']."'";

Comment: Hahaha, thank you very much @Anant . That was very helpfull! If you post this as an answer I will use it :)

Comment: I will accept it in 8 minutes, I have to wait before i can put it to the answer @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Anant Partial solution. `:)` I gave a full explanation. That counts. `:)` You didn't explain why it happens, and we both have a difference of `12 seconds`, which I used to explain it well. An answer should not be just do this and you'll get it, will be like you don't teach the person.

Comment: A partial solution is that which solves only some part of the problem not the complete problem. explanation only add information about the logic, it didn't make a solution partial or full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `'`(single quotes) around your column-name from your query like below:-

```
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$_GET['v']."'";
```

Note:- Instead of `'`(single quotes) use back-ticks. because single-quotes(`'`) used for values and back-ticks used for `column-name` as well as `table-name` too.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's a wrong way of query syntax. You need to use back-ticks and not `'`s:

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE 'username'='".$_GET['v']."'";
//-------------------------------------------^--------^
```

Change it to:

```
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$_GET['v']."'";
```

**Note:**

- ``` `` ``` - For columns.
- `''` - For values.